# Integrating a function with singularities using scipy's quad routine

Tags: python, scipy, quad

I am using the `quad` function from `scipy.integrate v0.19.1` to integrate functions with a square-root like singularity at each end of the integration interval such as for example

```
In [1]: quad(lambda x: 1/sqrt(1-x**2), -1, 1)
```

(I use the `sqrt` function from `numpy v1.12.0`) which immediately yields the correct result pi:

```
Out[1]: (3.141592653589591, 6.200897573194197e-10)
```

According to the documentation of the `quad` function the keyword `points` should be used to indicate the locations of singularities or discontinuities of the integrand, but if I indicate the points `[1, -1]` where the above integrand is singluar I get a Warning and `nan` as result:

```
In [2]: quad(lambda x: 1/sqrt(1-x**2), -1, 1, points=[-1, 1])

RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
IntegrationWarning: Extremely bad integrand behavior occurs at some
points of the integration interval.

Out[2]: (nan, nan)
```

Can someone clarify, why `quad` produces these problems if the singularities of the integrand are specified and just runs fine if these points are not indicated?

**EDIT:**
I think I figured out the correct solution for this problem. For the case someone else encounters similar problems I quickly want to share my findings:

I you want to integrate a function of the form `f(x)*g(x)` with a smooth function `f(x)` and `g(x) = (x-a)**alpha * (b-x)**beta`, where `a` and `b` are the the integration limits and `g(x)` has singularities at these limits if `alpha, beta < 0`, then you are supposed to just integrate `f(x)` using `g(x)` as *weighting function*. For the `quad` routine, this is possible using the `weight` and `wvar` arguments. With these arguments you are also able to handle singularities of different kinds and problematic oscillatory behavior. The weighting function `g(x)` defined above can be used by setting `weight='alg'` and using `wvar=(alpha, beta)` to specify the exponents in `g(x)`.

Since `1/sqrt(1-x**2) = (x+1)**(-1/2) * (1-x)**(-1/2)` I can now handle the integral as follows:

```
In [1]: quad(lambda x: 1, -1, 1, weight='alg', wvar=(-1/2, -1/2))
Out[1]: (3.1415926535897927, 9.860180640534107e-14)
```

which yields the correct answer `pi` with a very high accuracy, no matter if I use the argument `points=(-1, 1)` or not (which, as far as I understand now, should only be used, if the singularities/discontinuities can not be handled by choosing an appropriate weighting function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `points` is meant for singularities/discontinuities that occur *within* the interval of integration. It is not intended for endpoints of the interval. So, in your example the version without `points` is the correct approach.  (I can't pinpoint what goes wrong when endpoints are included in `points` without diving into FORTRAN code that SciPy wraps.)

Compare with the following example, where singularities occur within the interval of integration:

```
>>> quad(lambda x: 1/sqrt(abs(1-x**2)), -2, 2)
(inf, inf)
>>> quad(lambda x: 1/sqrt(abs(1-x**2)), -2, 2, points = [-1, 1])
(5.775508447436837, 7.264979728915932e-10)
```

Here the inclusion of `points` is appropriate, and yields the correct result, while without `points` the output is worthless.

Comment: Hi Walt, thank you for your kind answer! I think this is the correct way to go.